# tkinter through VNC without physical display

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, vnc

My setup is:

- a Raspberry Pi, running the latest Raspbian (fully updated), a self-compiled Python 3.3.3
- a Mac running Mavericks (10.9)

I'm AFP-ed, SSH-ed and VNC-ed to my RPi, and I can run all the command-line scripts I wrote, and also I can open any installed GUI applications, however, when I want to run a tkinter-based GUI app, to control some hardwares connected to the GPIO, I'm having this error message:

[image]

```
Client is not authorized to connect to ServerTraceback (most recent call last):
    ...
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1"
```

My guess is, that this is related to the fact, that there is no physical display attached to the RPi, although I don't know how to solve this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't do this but window manager in linux works as client-server. Linux has variable DISPLAY (`echo $DISPLAY`) which inform the server where to send windows/graphics - where is the client. In computer with monitor `DISPLAY` is `:0.0` but it can be `:IP_address.display_number`

Comment: @furas all right then, so what are you suggesting? (`echo $DISPLAY` shows `:1`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12014/tkinter-through-vnc-without-physical-display) on RaspberryPi Stack Exchange site, and [@hildred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2965906/hildred) had a beautiful solution for this:

Write these few lines to `etc/sudoers`*:

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY"
Defaults    env_keep += "XAUTHORITY"
```

And these few lines to `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -z "$XAUTHORITY" ]; then
    if [ -e $HOME/.Xauthority ]; then
        export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority;
    fi;
fi
```

---

**On a Raspbian this will be `etc/sudoers.d/README` for example*

Answer (score 1):

A person on the Raspberry Pi forums [solved a similar problem with tkinter](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=26934&p=242112#p242853):

> A simple work around is to give root the proper authorization to use
>   the X11 connection. Again, within a LXTerminal window:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo xauth add `xauth list`
```

Comment: this is overkill and somewhat dangerous on multiuser machines. Just allowing sudo to export XAUTHORITY is cleaner.

Comment: I upvote this answer, because I think this solution could work, although I prefer the one of @hildred.

Comment: @PeterVaro it works Just fine until /root/.Xauthority gets so big you  that you start experiencing delays, so one of the bright boys decides to delete it.